# Past and present in same sentence

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

- It **was** not about me Now I **have** to rise above

In this sentence structure, **was** and **have** are used together. Is this the correct form? If yes, can we join the part with past tense  and the part with present tense, connecting them with a comma? Like this:

- It **was** not about me, now I **have** to rise above...

Comment: I **edited** your question; the answer **is**  "Yes". But I **prefer** a semicolon, as you **saw** in the previous sentence.

Comment: Is your first example not missing a period after _me_?

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule prohibiting different time references within a single sentence. Whether it's "correct" is a matter of whether there is good reason for it.

However, joining two independent clauses with a bare comma is usually frowned on; you would do better to join them with a semicolon or a comma + *and* until you are familiar with accepted uses of the 'comma splice'.